# is there any way to disable compiler optimisation for a specific line of code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, compiler-construction

is there any way to disable compiler optimisation for a specific line of code  in Visual studio?

Comment: What is the specific usage scenario you have?  There may be other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Often a line of code is optimised taking in to account lots of other lines of code - so turning off optimisation for one line doesn't seem to make much sense.  Is it allowed to use precomputed constant values from earlier lines, for example?

Comment: Simple use case is to be able to add a breakpoint to that line of code, without having to run without optimizations for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 150):

No.

Only on a function-by-function basis using the [optimize pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx):

```
 #pragma optimize( "[optimization-list]", {on | off} )
```

> The optimize pragma must appear
>   outside a function and takes effect at
>   the first function defined after the
>   pragma is seen. The on and off
>   arguments turn options specified in
>   the optimization-list on or off.

usage:

```
#pragma optimize( "", off )
.
.
.
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that having an empty [optimization-list] is perfectly fine.