# Turn off C++ optimizations for certain segments of code g++

Tags: c++, debugging, optimization, g++

Sorry if this is a really stupid question.

I am trying to track down a bug in some C++. The code works in debug mode, but when I apply optimizations with -03 in the makefile it gives incorrect results.

Is it possible to turn off the optimizations for certain functions in the source so that I can locate which routine it is that is broken?

I'm using g++ with -std=c++11

Comment: very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713320/is-there-any-way-to-disable-compiler-optimisation-for-a-specific-line-of-code (visual studio)

Comment: and why not turn off optimizations everywhere?  You do have a DEBUG build, don't you?  If not, you should not be asking this question, you should be asking "how do I set up a DEBUG build?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent gcc optimizing some statements in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219829/how-to-prevent-gcc-optimizing-some-statements-in-c)

Comment: you can also explore other options like compiling with clang in debug/release mode or disable some g++ optimizations as with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: You could put the function you want to disable in a separate source file and compile that with different optimization switch