# In Visual Studio, How to prevent my useful function being optimized by the compiler?

Tags: compiler-optimization

I did a template string operation class which can operate std::string and MFC CString.
It workes fine on the Debug version.
It does work on the Release version.
By my investigation, I found that at least one useful function is optimized.
checkChars is optimized which is supposed to be called in the split. (checkChars isn't being called.)

```
static bool checkChars(const TCHARTYPE& c, const TCHARTYPE* chrs)
        {
            for ( ;*chrs ;chrs++)
            {
                if (c == *chrs)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
void split(const TSTRING& s, vector<TSTRING>& v, const TCHARTYPE* separator, bool bKeepEmptyParts = false)
{
...
//here at() is called, but checkChars isn't
if (checkChars(at(s, i), separator))
...
}
```

The VS Optimization is

> Maximize Speed (/O2)

. I found use

> Custom

can prevent the Optimization of my useful function.
But I want to know why, and I don't want to change the project settings, Can I just modify my code to make it work?

Edit:

After a long time, I realized that the real problem is not Optimization, is that "at()" fuction doesn't return the expected char reference. TSTRING here is CString MFC which does not return a TCHAR reference. The compiler found this would not work, so "optimized" it.

Answer (score 4):

[is there any way to disable compiler optimisation for a specific line of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713320/is-there-any-way-to-disable-compiler-optimisation-for-a-specific-line-of-code)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx

```
#pragma optimize( "", off )
.
.
.
#pragma optimize( "", on )
```