# Turning off optimization for all files in a folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

Is there a way to turn off optimization in Visual Studio for all translation units in a folder?

For a specific file one can use something like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4713351/10774817).

Some workarounds that come to my mind (all not perfect, i.e. too much manual work):

- include a header in each cpp which can easily toggle optimization
- use some script to prepend turning off optimization for each file

Comment: Are you building from the IDE? Then you can have different settings for individual files - just select one or more files in the Solution Explorer and change their settings.

Comment: On the other hand, having Debug mode for some files and Release mode for other files will most often not work. For example class layouts might be different.

Comment: As BoP mentions, you can set different optimization settings for individual files. But I would restrict it to the optimization settings (`/O2` etc) and not change stuff that adds or removes debug checks (e.g. preprocessor definitions such as `NDEBUG`, `_DEBUG`, etc.), since those might change the ABI, especially of types in the standard library.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer, it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used the power shell script to complete your requirements, you need to change the file path in the code to the path of .cpp in your project, the sample code is as follows

```
$cpps = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\asdasds\Project44\Project44" -Filter *.cpp).fullname
$line = '#pragma optimize( "", {off} )'
$cpps| ForEach-Object {
    $line + "`n" + (Get-Content -path $_ -Raw) | Set-Content -Path $_
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I hoped that there would be a "nicer/cleaner" solution from within the IDE or something similar. BTW it should probably be `#pragma optimize("", off)`, i.e. empty list and no curly braces.

Comment: @jack Hi,you could change it however you want. And if you want VS to launch this feature, I suggest you go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem) to put forward your needs.